# How to "flatten" a 3D mesh into a 2D shape in Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to flatten a 3D mesh into a 2D shape. What I'm trying to achieve is something like [this](http://it.tinypic.com/r/34skv93/9)

Basically what you see in the image is a given mesh and its silhouettes along different views. I'd like to do the same for any given mesh with Three.js, but I don't know how can I get the silhouette.

I thought of two possible solutions:

1) Copy the mesh and scale it along the given axis so that it get flattened (for example, if I want to get the silhouette of the shape I see looking from positive Z to negative, I'd simply scale it like this:

```
myMesh.scale.z = 0.001 // Small value to make it "2D-like"
```

Problem: I'm copying and redrawing a mesh that could be potentially very large, so that's not very efficient.

2) Project the vertices of the mesh to a 2D plane so that they're all at the same level and then create lines among the vertices.

Problem: Put like this it doesn't work at all, because I lose information about how the vertices are connected as faces. The resulting shape will depend completely on how the order the vertices are projected.

For example, if we consider this [mesh](http://it.tinypic.com/r/14n1bt3/9)
and I project the vertices "in front of me" from that point of view I would get [these points](http://it.tinypic.com/r/wi7wn9/9) (more or less), but I wouldn't know how to connect them.

How should I proceed?

Comment: mesh.geometry has all the information about how the vertices are connected. just draw all the triangles into another canvas using getContext('2d') and use that canvas as a texture

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making additional render passes to textures with [orthogonal projection](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) and creating planes with these textures on them.

If you don't need material details of object it is worth to change its material to some simple material. Also if your planes and object are in the same scene, you might want to make them invisible when you render with ortho.

In three.js [WebGLRenderTarget](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Renderers/WebGLRenderTarget) could be used for rendering to texture, [OrthographicCamera](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Cameras/OrthographicCamera) for getting ortho projection and [MeshBasicMaterial](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Materials/MeshBasicMaterial) as simple material.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that might be too difficult to do for me. You see, I need to implement this feature in a bigger project, and adding a rendering pass would be too complicated because of the structure of the project. 
Basically what I have available is just a scene object, to which I have to add these silhouettes, without adding/changing rendering passes